# java : Does using buffered input stream make the conversion of input streams to byte[] more efficient?

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I want to convert an input stream to byte[] and I'm using `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)`. Will it make more efficient by using a wrapper like `BufferedInputStream` for the inputStream ? Does it save memory ?

Answer (score 2):

> Will it make more efficient by wrapper like BufferedInputStream for
>   the inputStream ?

Not by any significance. `IOUtils.toByteArray` reads data into a buffer of 4096 bytes. `BufferedInputStream` uses a 8192 bytes buffer by default.
Using `BufferedInputStream` does fewer IO reads, but you need a very fast data source to notice any difference.

IF you read an InputStream one byte at a time (or a few bytes), then using a BufferedInputStream really improves performance because it reduces the number of operating system calls by a factor 8000. And operating system calls take a lot of time, comparatively.

> Does it save memory ?

No. `IOUtils.toByteArray` will create a `new byte[4096]` regardless if whether pass in a buffered or an unbuffered InputStream. A `BufferdedInputStream` costs a bit more memory to create. But nothing significant.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand your answer. In my scenario, I'm trying save byte[] of hundreds of files from file system to database.  During the conversion of these hundreds of files, sometimes I run out of heap space. So using the buffered input stream doesn't make any significant difference if I get to use it?

Comment: @AravindS if each file represents a list of entities, you are inserting to your database, the best way to deal with it, instead of calling `IOUtils.toByteArray` reading whole file at once, read it by batches, e.g. take first 1000 of entities in file, write them to database, commit transaction, read next 1000 then, and you will always need to allocate memory only for one chank of entities, which size you can control.

Comment: That's what I'm doing inside a for loop. I was facing this problem repeatedly. So I'm reading one file at a time, committing the transaction. And repeat this cycle as long as I have any files. I did this just to see if it works but I still face out of memory exception.

Comment: @AravindS yes, that is your problem, read my comment carefully, `IOUtils.toByteArray` will read your file completely at once, so you will hold whole file content in a memory, if you instead will call `readLine()` and read 1000 lines, then submit them to database, then proceed to next 1000lines in current file, then you will have only 1000 lines of your file in memory at one moment of the time, not the whole file.

Comment: Okay, is it like, to read the first 1000 lines, save it as byte array to database, read the next 1000 lines and save that to the database until reaching the end of the file?

Comment: @AravindS yes, I don't really know your database model and what you are trying to write there, so if each file consists from multiple entities inside you can use that approach, if the whole file is one single entity you can do the same but when inserting it to database, your query can append your current 1000 lines to previous ones, however if one file is mapped to a single database entry, and this entry doesn't fit into your heap its kind of a problem anyway, because you would be unable to work with it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of final memory consumption it wouldn't help, as you anyway will need to move the whole stream to `byte[]`, the size of the array would be the same, so memory consumption would be the same.

What `BufferedInputStream` does, it wraps another stream and instead writing to it directly it buffers your input into internal buffer and writes to underlying stream only when it `closes/flushes` or when the internal buffer is full. It can make your write operations faster, as you will do them in batches instead of writing directly each time, but it wouldn't help if you reading it from another side.